# Is the output of all kinds of machine learning models binary or can the end values be interpreted in other ways?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm just wrapping my head around the topic and building a simple neural network from scratch as I go. I'm trying out different data types to hold weights, values and biases as well as different activation functions and back propagation techniques.

While I have some success with treating the input/output layers as binary values with a certain threshold (for example an output of [0.97, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1] would translate into 1100 or 12), I can't seem to derive consistent meaning out of the individual values themselves.

Perhaps it is the size of my models (<10k parameters) or that I train them very little but I was wondering if this is an avenue even worth pursuing. Basically, are there any NN's out there where the exact values of the output are meaningful beyond just being a fuzzy bit?

Comment: FYI, there is also an [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com) where you might get more in-depth answers (but would need to make sure your question met their standards). A couple of relevant questions from a quick search: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7911/34038 and https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/28406/34038

Comment: What is the output supposed to *represent*? They aren't just numbers that are there for no reason! What is the network trying to learn?

Comment: NNs generally output a vector of floats that can be interpreted as probabilities. You can go further and round them up/down to 0/1 to make decisions, but that's not always appropriate. E.g. for a labelling problem you'd have one output neuron per label, and then might display the labels with the top three probabilities. You associate the output neurons with a particular meaning via training. If neuron #3 means “cat found” and you train the NN on a cat image and the neuron doesn't output 1.0, you'd back-propagate the error in order to update weights. 10k params is large for a toy model though.